# how to overcome undefined behavior in strings concatenation?

Tags: c, arrays, string, concatenation

I want to concatenate strings in c. Therefore I wrote the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main () {
    char str1[20], str2[20];
    int i=0;
    
    scanf("%20s",str1);
    getchar();
    scanf("%20s",str2);
    getchar();
    char str3[strlen(str1)+strlen(str2)];

    for(i=0; str1[i]; i++){
        str3[i]=str1[i];
    }
    
    for(i=0; str2[i]; i++){
        str3[strlen(str1)+i]=str2[i];
    }
    
    printf("\nSum is: %s\n", str3);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Why do I get random characters at the end of the sum str3?
I know there are a function to do that, but I wanted to do it an elementary way.

Comment: Any reason you're not using `strcat`?

Comment: You should provide an extra `char` for `'\0'` here: `char str3[strlen(str1)+strlen(str2)];`.

Comment: Yes I did not want to use functions.

Comment: You didn't add the NULL byte at the end of the string. Just add the line `str3[strlen(str1) + strlen(str2)] = 0;`, BTW you have lots of bad practice code here...

Comment: Aside: `"%20s"` should be `"%19s"`

Comment: You mean:     char str3[strlen(str1)+strlen(str2)+1]?

Comment: @WeatherVane: Why 19?

Comment: Because, in this case, `19` is the maximum string length that the buffer can hold. This is distinct from `fgets()` where the `size` passed is the actual buffer size, which will include the nul terminator and, possibly, a newline.

Comment: If I read in strings of length 20, then I change str1[21] and leave %20 isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are invoking *undefined behavior* by having `printf()` read out-of-bounds of `str3`.

You must

1. Allocate one more element for terminating null character.
   i.e. `char str3[strlen(str1)+strlen(str2)];` should be `char str3[strlen(str1)+strlen(str2)+1];`
2. Put a terminating null character at the end of the resulting string.
   i.e. Add `str3[strlen(str1)+strlen(str2)] = '\0';` before the `printf()` statement.

Comment: Thank you very much:)